# Get render array or output for any route I pass?

Tags: theming

I need the ability to get the rendered HTML output or even just the render array simply by passing the route and nothing more.

Is this possible?  Can't seem to find any way to do this.

Thanks

EDIT: more info on what we are trying to do:

We are using the elasticsearch_connector module and we want to index pages created via views or via custom modules.  There are a list of about 10 items specifically we want to index so that they are returned via search results.

None of the things we are trying to index return anything different depending on whether we are logged in or not.  None of them require parameters, either.

If there's a better way to handle this other than just indexing the rendered HTML directly to elasticsearch, that would be great if someone could help with that, too.

Comment: A lot of routes require parameters. Some routes return different things depending on the logged in user, etc. Some routes could provide json or trigger ajax commands. This doesn't really seem like a reasonable or possible request. Maybe you can update your question with some information about what you're trying to accomplish and why.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the original question with more details on what we are trying to do.

Comment: These two statements: _we want to index pages created via views_ and _None of them require parameters, either._ are incompatible...Views pages do require route parameters, specifically the machine name of the View. So I guess the direct answer to _I need the ability to get the rendered HTML output or even just the render array simply by passing the route and nothing more._ is that you can't, your requirements mean route parameters will need to be determined and passed along. But either way that's going to be be, if not difficult, then long-winded. You'd be better off building the render...

Comment: ...arrays from the normal API (ViewExecutable methods for the View, the theme function for the custom module output, etc)